# Is there a way to delete all my Stack Overflow questions and start over?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, self-delete

I've been asking what amounts to a series of evolving questions on Stack Overflow. I ask a question, get a response, do some reading, do some experimentation, and then formulate a new question to try to move forward to the next step.

Basically I'm stuck and think it may be helpful if I could have all my Stack Overflow questions and answers deleted in order to move forward.

Now I know that I want to **extend** my existing design and not replace it. I don't want to add a thread, a handler, a Service, or use Async Task, or AIDL, or any answer I have received so far. I want to *extend* my existing design.

I am working with open source code. It already has a *nice and solid background thread* which I don't need or want to replace or redesign. I simply want to *extend the existing design*.

So I want to delete everything and start over. I simply want to extend the existing open source design that already has *one really nice background thread* that I want to leverage to plot some data in a new activity.

In fact I already have it working using a static method. But people have criticized this solution without saying why. I would like to know if this is a good solution. Is it thread safe? Do I have a deadlock issue? Is my solution a fragile one and am I lucky that it's working at all? Or very simply put what are the proper ways to *extend* the existing design?

OK? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just ask new questions in the new direction that you want to take your design.  Keeping the other questions around may help someone else later down the road, which is one of the main goals of the SE sites.

Answer (score 11):

While I don't understand why "it would be helpful" to you to have all your questions and answers deleted, **that most certainly would be detrimental to the community**. Your questions are not only for you, others worked to answer them and hope that they will help the next person who has a similar question. That's why people see you question, which according to the title is a request for mass deletion of content, as a bad idea. Here on Meta, people use downvoting to express disagreement (in this case saying "Users deleting all their content is a bad idea").

If you really want to start over, go get a new OpenID, create a new account, and start from the beginning again.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that questions and answers should **NEVER** be deleted.

However, I think a user should be able to disassociate himself from a posted answer/question.  As time goes on we must be able to remove our digital footprints.

Does anyone think this is a good idea?

Comment: this is just not correct; see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/ under 'Why do you allow content to be deleted?'